# Rectangle with Double Values vs Int Values

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d, affinetransform

I am making a game in java and my player can be rotated 360 degrees. I have to make a hitbox that rotates and moves with the player. I used a Rectangle to do this, however, it uses int values instead of double values and as a result, the hitbox's positioning is a little off (because I add double values to integers). How do I fix this?

I've already tried Rectangle2D.Double but I can't modify the x and y values.

**Here is the relevant code:**

Declaration:

```
private Rectangle hitbox;
private Shape transformed;
```

Initialization

```
hitbox = new Rectangle((int) x, (int) y + 20, currentImg.getWidth(), currentImg.getHeight()/2 + 20);
transformed = hitbox;
```

Movement

```
hitbox.x += xM * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));
hitbox.y += yM * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
```

Rotation

```
AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
transform.rotate(Math.toRadians(this.angle), hitbox.x + hitbox.getWidth()/2, hitbox.y + hitbox.getHeight()/2);
transformed = transform.createTransformedShape(hitbox);
```

Comment: Have a look at the graphics 2D shape API, starting with [`Rectangle2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html) and [Working with Geometry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/index.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've already tried Rectangle2D.Double but I can't modify the x and y values like this.

Comment: You can use `setFrame` and `setRect` if needed.  If you want `double` support, this is the class you're looking for

Comment: You could store the `double` values for `x` and `y` in separate variables, and do all the arithmetic with those.  Then set `hitbox.x` and `hitbox.y` to the rounded versions of those variables whenever they need to be updated.